Can a superGM always draw another as white?
Review of related literature:

Previously this was asked for GMs regardless of colour:

1.1 - Why do many people think that top grand masters can always reach a draw?

1.2 - Can a grandmaster always draw?



And then superGM/GM vs engine:

2.1 - Could a top ranked GM draw against Stockfish using drawish opening lines in classical chess?

2.2 - Can a human defeat an engine in a 10-game match if he is given the White pieces and draw odds in every game?



And additionally Bobby Fischer did say re the 1972 & 1975 classical WCCs, but no one really brought up colour. (Maybe because white was not as powerful then? Idk.)



Fischer had, prior to his 1972 match against Spassky, felt that the first-to-12½-points format was not fair, since it encouraged whoever was leading to play for draws instead of wins. He himself adopted this strategy in the match: after having taken a comfortable lead, he drew games 14–20. With each game, he coasted closer to the title, while Spassky lost a chance to fight back. This style of chess offended Fischer.

Question: Now just superGM vs another superGM (or below) and this time the colour matters : In classical time controls, how often does a superGM, as white, fail to at least draw another superGM (or below), when all they need is a draw in a game to eg win a 1v1 match or a round robin/swiss tournament?

Cf: In the 2016 & 2023 classical WCC's, the 1st losses were as white. The ones who lost 1st indeed won the match but only on tiebreaks : they did not win the classical portion, and in particular they did not equalise in black wins.

Note: Btw, of course Hell no for chess960.



The FIDE world cup is a knockout-style tournament consisting of many 1v1 matches of two games.  One could scrape data from there and find out.  One side effect of that format is that in situations where all White needs is a draw, Black is necessarily playing for a win as well, as a draw would still eliminate Black.  The only benefit for Black to draw (rather than lose) is 5 ELO points.

Ok I did this for the 2023 World Cup, both open & women's sections.
I recorded the games for Rounds 3 to the end. But then for rounds 1 & 2, I didn't record anymore. Just trust me bro/sis/sib. The 'in table' refers to the rounds 3 to end while 'out of table' refers to rounds 1 & 2. I didn't bother to check the ratings anymore, so maybe you can just consider everyone from rounds 3 onwards as respectively, superGMs & superWGMs (approximately equal to female GMs).
Question: For the case of the black-white player (player who has black 1st and white 2nd) who wins as black in 1st round: Does the black-white player at least draw as white in the 2nd round?

Yes = BW player drew or won when playing white after winning as black
No = BW player lost when playing white after winning as black


Statistics :



 
Total
 




Yes
34
87.18%


No
5
12.82%


Total
39
 


 
 
 


 
In table
 


Yes
7
77.78%


No
2
22.22%


Total
9
 


 
 
 


 
Out of table
 


Yes
27
90.00%


No
3
10.00%


Total
30
 



Women's:



 
Total
 




Yes
24
80.00%


No
6
20.00%


Total
30
 


 
 
 


 
In table
 


Yes
4
80.00%


No
1
20.00%


Total
5
 


 
 
 


 
Out of table
 


Yes
20
80.00%


No
5
20.00%


Total
25
 




Discussion :

Open: 90% draw in rounds 1-2. Then 77.8% onwards. 87.18% total.

In the open section, there's an 87.18% chance, almost 90% overall that white can at least draw.


Women's: 80% draw throughout.

In the women's section, there's an 80% chance overall that white can at least draw.




Database :

Open :



Round

 
 
 
 
 
 




Finals
Nothing
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Semi-finals
Nothing
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Quarter-finals
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Pragg
Lost
White
Black
Won
Arjun
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/06-01/Praggnanandhaa_R-Erigaisi_Arjun


Pragg
Won
Black
White
Lost
Arjun
No
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/06-02/Erigaisi_Arjun-Praggnanandhaa_R


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Gukesh
Lost
White
Black
Won
Magnus
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/06-01/Gukesh_D-Carlsen_Magnus


Gukesh
Draw
Black
White
Draw
Magnus
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/06-02/Carlsen_Magnus-Gukesh_D


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 5 (Octo-finals)
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Gukesh
Won
Black
White
Lost
Wang Hao
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/05-01/Wang_Hao-Gukesh_D


Gukesh
Draw
White
Black
Draw
Wang Hao
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/05-02/Gukesh_D-Wang_Hao


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Nils Grandelius
Lost
White
Black
Won
Arjun
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/05-01/Grandelius_Nils-Erigaisi_Arjun


Nils Grandelius
Draw
Black
White
Draw
Arjun
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/05-02/Erigaisi_Arjun-Grandelius_Nils


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 4
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Alexey Sarana
Won
Black
White
Lost
Wesley
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/04-01/So_Wesley-Sarana_Alexey


Alexey Sarana
Draw
White
Black
Draw
Wesley
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/04-02/Sarana_Alexey-So_Wesley


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 3
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Vincent Keymer
Won
Black
White
Lost
Amin Tabatabaei
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-01/Tabatabaei_M_Amin-Keymer_Vincent


Vincent Keymer
Won
White
Black
Lost
Amin Tabatabaei
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-02/Keymer_Vincent-Tabatabaei_M_Amin


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Jingyao Tin
Lost
White
Black
Won
Rasmus Svane
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-01/Tin_Jingyao-Svane_Rasmus


Jingyao Tin
Draw
Black
White
Draw
Rasmus Svane
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-02/Svane_Rasmus-Tin_Jingyao


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Daniil
Lost
White
Black
Won
Daniele Vocaturo
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-01/Dubov_Daniil-Vocaturo_Daniele


Daniil
Draw
Black
White
Draw
Daniele Vocaturo
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-02/Vocaturo_Daniele-Dubov_Daniil


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Radoslaw Wojtaszek
Lost
White
Black
Won
Ivan Schitco
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-01/Wojtaszek_Radoslaw-Schitco_Ivan


Radoslaw Wojtaszek
Won
Black
White
Lost
Ivan Schitco
No
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-world-cup/03-02/Schitco_Ivan-Wojtaszek_Radoslaw


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 2
14 Yes 0 No
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 1
13 Yes 3 No
 
 
 
 
 
 




Women's



Round

 
 
 
 
 
 




Finals
Nothing
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Semi-finals
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Aleksandra Goryachkina
Won
Black
White
Lost
Zhongyi
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/06-01/Tan_Zhongyi-Goryachkina_Aleksandra


Aleksandra Goryachkina
Draw
White
Black
Draw
Zhongyi
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/06-02/Goryachkina_Aleksandra-Tan_Zhongyi


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Quarter-finals
Nothing
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 4 (Octo-finals)
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Bela Khotenashvili
Won
Black
White
Lost
Humpy
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/04-01/Koneru_Humpy-Khotenashvili_Bella


Bela Khotenashvili
Lost
White
Black
Won
Humpy
No
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/04-02/Khotenashvili_Bella-Koneru_Humpy


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 3
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Medina Warda Aulia
Won
Black
White
Lost
Alina Bivol
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/03-01/Bivol_Alina-Aulia_Medina_Warda


Medina Warda Aulia
Draw
White
Black
Draw
Alina Bivol
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/03-02/Aulia_Medina_Warda-Bivol_Alina


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Nurgyul Salimova
Won
Black
White
Lost
Mary Ann Gomes
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/03-01/Gomes_Mary_Ann-Salimova_Nurgyul


Nurgyul Salimova
Won
White
Black
Lost
Mary Ann Gomes
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/03-02/Salimova_Nurgyul-Gomes_Mary_Ann


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Nino Batsiashvili
Won
Black
White
Lost
Zhao Xue
 
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/03-01/Zhao_Xue-Batsiashvili_Nino


Nino Batsiashvili
Draw
White
Black
Draw
Zhao Xue
Yes
https://www.chess.com/events/2023-fide-chess-womens-world-cup/03-02/Batsiashvili_Nino-Zhao_Xue


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 2
5 Yes 2 No
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Zhao Xue
 
 
 
No
Carissa Yip
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 


Round 1
15 Yes 3 No
 
 
 
 
 
 


 
 
 
 
Yes
Carissa Yip
 
 



